# Reading File With Qt Creator does not terminate

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, readfile, getline

I have the following simple Code:

```
ifstream f; 
string line;
f.open("path", ios::in); 
while (getline(f, line))
{
    cout << line << endl;
}
cout << "Trying to close\n";
f.close();
```

This code runs fine in Visual Studio 2012 but when I try to execute it in Qt Creator, the whole file is read but then it just stops, which means "Trying to close" is not printed. The while loop only exits when I close the program, then "Trying to close" is displayed.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my simple code, or is this some speciality of Qt Creator which I'm not aware of?

Comment: Could you change the line to the following and try again? `cout << "Trying to close" << endl;` The text might be written but not be flushed.

Comment: Also Qt Creator can be configured to use the same compiler as Visual Studio, so the behavior of the code may just be a difference between MingW and MSVC's implementation of `cout` with `flush`.  Also I would switch to using `qDebug()` instead of `cout`.  It adds spaces and endlines for you automatically.

Comment: qDebug() is for printing debug output (and might not happen at all in release builds), not for output you rely on. So it's not a good replacement for std::cout, in general.

Comment: Do you have more code in your `main` function?  Qt Widgets application normally starts an event processing loop, which is infinite, using something like `app.exec();`.

Comment: This code is called within its own function.
@SimonWarta: thank you, this solved the problem!